# Question about the object adress of a return object with the type of boost::function &

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-function

**Why the addresses of this two variable(i.e `hoofunc` and `Ctx::hookFunc4Boost`)** **are not same** whereas the `Ctx::getBoostHookFun()` return a left reference to `Ctx::hookFunc4Boost`?

I intend to avoid the copy of a temporary object by returning a left reference to `Ctx::hookFunc4Boost`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Ctx
{
public:
const boost::function<void((void*))>& getBoostHookFun(void)
{
    std::cout << "inner hookFunc4Boost:" << (void*)(&hookFunc4Boost) << std::endl;
    return hookFunc4Boost;
}

private:
boost::function<void(void*)> hookFunc4Boost;

};

int main()
{
    Ctx ctx;
    Ctx *pCtx = &ctx;
    const boost::function<void((void*))> hookFunc = pCtx->getBoostHookFun();
    std::cout << "outer hookFunc:" << (void*)(&hookFunc) << std::endl;
}
```

Here are the outputs:

```
inner hookFunc4Boost:0x7fffffffdf28
outer hookFunc:0x7fffffffd540
```

Comment: Sorry, it's a clerical error. I have edited it now. @Jarod42

Comment: Note that you did avoid the copy of a *temporary* object, as neither `ctx.hookFunc4Boost` nor `hookFunc` are temporaries.

Comment: Also note that `boost::function` is an unnecessary complication. You could change each occurrence of `boost::function<void((void*))>` to, for example, `unsigned` and see the same phenomenon.

Comment: @JaMiT Thank you for your attention to my question. So why the addresses of the two are not same since this no temporary object at all.

Comment: @JaMiT I see, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of JaMiT, I think I find the answer.

Here is a demo code(https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=12bc35c31c9eb605):

```
#include <iostream>

class Ctx
{
public:
Ctx(int cnt):m_cnt(cnt){}

const int& getCnt(void)
{
    std::cout << "inner:" << (void*)&m_cnt << std::endl;
    return m_cnt;
}

private:
int m_cnt;

};

int main()
{
    Ctx ctx(6);
    Ctx *pCtx = &ctx;
    const int cnt = pCtx->getCnt();
    std::cout << "outer:" << (void*)&cnt << std::endl;
}
```

The variable `cnt` and `Ctx::m_cnt` are two different variables. So their addresses should be different. It still needs to call copy constructor when invoking `const int cnt = pCtx->getCnt();`. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid a copy just change your variable to a reference:

```
const auto& hookFunc = pCtx->getBoostHookFun();
```

Comment: Sorry, it's a clerical error. I have edited it now.

Comment: And yet my answer remains the same.  Put the code I have shown and try again.

Comment: I tried it.But  I can't see any difference between `const boost::function<void((void*))> hookFunc = pCtx->getBoostHookFun();` and `const auto& hookFunc = pCtx->getBoostHookFun();`.